# How can you compute grand totals in an aggregate view

Tags: 7, views

I have a aggregate view in D7 that is working great.  The only thing is, I want to add a grand total line to the view.  What is the best way to add a grand total to the view?  Here is a sample of my data.

```
Dept  Squad    # of Rpts   # Vols   # of Hours  Value of Hours
AK     AK-11        3          6        124.00           2,745.36
FL    FL-893       24         41        664.50          14,712.04
```

What I would like to do is the above plus a grand total line like:

```
Dept  Squad    # of Rpts   # Vols   # of Hours  Value of Hours
AK     AK-11        3          6        124.00           2,745.36
FL    FL-893       24         41        664.50          14,712.04

  Grand total      27         47        789.50          17,457.40
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for you help.

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

The project page says:

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the
> Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug
> in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies
> numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines
> calculated rows).

For more information go through the module documentation.